# How many Digits are there in $2020^{2020}$

Tags: logarithms

How many digits are there in $2020 ^{2020} $ ?

In solution, I first factorized the given number to be $202^{2020}\times10^{2020}$

This made it sufficient to calculate the total digit number of $202^{2020}$ and then add $2020$ digits (for the zeroes in $10^{2020}$ ) to find the answer

Now I found out all powers of $202$ up to $7th$ power, by hand-multiplication. What I figured out is:

**For every $202^{1+3n}$  no. of digits in the answer is $ 3 + 7n $**

This way the answer of this question should lead to $6734$ digits where, $202^{2020}$ has  $4714$ digits, and $2020$ more digits for $10^{2020}$

My question is, whether the formula I mentioned in bold letter, is always applicable up to any natural number value of $n$ ?

Comment: Hint:  the number of digits in $N$ is $\lceil \log_{10} N\rceil$  (where $\lceil x\rceil$ denotes the least integer which is not less than $x$).

Comment: To your numerical question:  No.  with $n=4$ we have that $202^{13}$ has $30$ digits but $3+7n=31$ and the gap continues to widen for larger $n$.

Comment: @lulu, can we use a method to solve this problem without calculator?

Comment: An exact answer?  Probably, but nothing leaps to mind.  To do it roughly, I'd approximate with $2^{2020}\times 10^{6060}$ and since $2^{10}\approx 10^3$ we'd then get around $10^{606}\times 10^{6060}=10^{6666}$ which would mean $6665$.  That's not terrible!  the correct answer (barring error) is $6677$.

Comment: @lulu To deal correctly with powers of $10$ e.g. $10$ has two digits you need the floor of the log plus one, rather than the ceiling. The functions are the same except at powers of $10$, so it makes no difference to he answer to the question.

Comment: @MarkBennet  Thanks for the correction!  You are, of course, absolutely correct.

Answer (score 2):

Let me use $\log x$ for the logarithm in base $10$ of $x$ and $\ln x$ for the natural logarithm.

You can do the computation by hand if you know $\log2=0.301030$ (which I had to memorize in school), $\ln10=2.302586$ (which I was supposed to memorize but never did) and the approximation $\ln(1+x)\approx x-x^2/2$ for $x$ close to $0$.
$$
\log202=\log200+\log\Bigl(1+\frac1{100}\Bigr)\approx2+\log2+\frac{1}{\ln10}\Bigl(\frac{1}{100}-\frac12\frac{1}{100^2}\Bigr).
$$

Answer (score 1):

Your finding

$$202^{1+3n}\to3+7n\text{ digits}$$

is only approximate.

Actually, using logarithms,

$$\log_{10}202^{1+3n}=(1+3n)\log_{10}202=2.3053513694\cdots+6.9160541083\cdots n.$$

Taking the ceiling, the two formulas give

$$0 \to 3 , 3 \\
1 \to 10 , 10 \\
2 \to 17 , 17 \\
3 \to 24 , 24 \\
4 \to 31 , 30 \\
5 \to 38 , 37 \\
6 \to 45 , 44 \\
7 \to 52 , 51 \\
8 \to 59 , 58 \\
9 \to 66 , 65 \\\cdots$$

---

The correct answer is

$$\lceil2020\log_{10}2020\rceil=6677.$$